# Filter out elements that occur less times than a minimum threshold

Tags: python, list-comprehension, counter, dictionary-comprehension

After trying to count the occurrences of an element in a list using the below code

```
from collections import Counter
A = ['a','a','a','b','c','b','c','b','a']
A = Counter(A)
min_threshold = 3
```

After calling Counter on `A` above, a counter object like this is formed:

```
>>> A
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2})
```

From here, how do I filter only `'a'` and `'b'` using minimum threshold value of `3`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Build your Counter, then use a dict comprehension as a second, filtering step.

```
{x: count for x, count in A.items() if count >= min_threshold}
# {'a': 4, 'b': 3}
```

Comment: This is suboptimal, there's no need to re-lookup every `A[x]` to get that item's `count`, just iterate directly over `for x, count in A.items()`

Answer (score 4):

As covered by [Satish BV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6059355/satish-bv), you can iterate over your Counter with a dictionary comprehension. You could use items (or iteritems for more efficiency and if you're on Python 2) to get a sequence of (key, value) tuple pairs.
And then turn that into a Counter.

```
my_dict = {k: v for k, v in A.iteritems() if v >= min_threshold}
filteredA = Counter(my_dict)
```

Alternatively, you could iterate over the original Counter and remove the unnecessary values.

```
for k, v in A.items():
    if v < min_threshold:
        A.pop(k)
```

Answer (score 4):

This looks nicer:

```
{ x: count for x, count in A.items() if count >= min_threshold }
```

Comment: In Python 3, you need to iterate over `for x, count in A.items()` to avoid `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the keys from the dictionary that are below `3`:

```
for key, cnts in list(A.items()):   # list is important here
    if cnts < min_threshold:
        del A[key]
```

Which gives you:

```
>>> A
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 3})
```